# How to Add An Attribute By Default to All Formtastic Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I want to add `:validate => true` to every formtastic form in my Rails 3 app. I've looked over the code to Formtastic and don't see an obvious hook for that. Before forking it and writing the code myself, I wanted to see if anyone had already solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but Justin French confirmed what I suspected. There is no current facility to do this in Formtastic. He suggested a wrapper, which I implemented as follows:

```
def validated_form_for(record_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options.reverse_merge!({:validate => true})
  semantic_form_for(record_name_or_array, options, &proc)
end
```

This handles the case where you want forms that are automatically client-side validated, but wish to be able to override it on a case by case basis.